# equivalence class of an inequiality

Tags: equivalence-relations

For the equivalence relation R=`{(x,y):x,y belong to the set of real numbers & |x-y|<4}` how would you determine the equivalence class? I'm particularly confused as to how one would do so for an inequality function involving an absolute value.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an equivalence relation so you can't find equivalence classes.

Specifically, we have for example
$$(0,3)\in R\quad\hbox{and}\quad (3,6)\in R\quad\hbox{but}\quad (0,6)\not\in R\ ,$$
so $R$ is not transitive.

Comment: oh I see. I wonder how I missed that. thanks for the answer, sorry for the elementary mistake.